# Special attributes in helper input field tag in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to add special attributes (like `aria-label`) into an input field tag function in a Rails view?

I tried these, but they did not work:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :name, "Name", aria: { label: 'Name' } %>
<%= radio_button_tag :name, "Name", 'aria-label' => 'Name' %>
```

Thanks in advance. I am using Rails 3.2.22.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :name, "Name", false, aria: { label: 'Name' } %>
```

You also need to specify the 'checked' parameter to match the method interface.

Also for reference see the Rails API:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Comment: Next time I'll check the API more thoroughly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Bryan Oemar, I checked the Rails API (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag) and found this:

```
radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})
```

I needed to specify the third parameter correctly. Here is the answer:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :name, "Name", false, 'aria-label' => 'Name' %>
```

**NB:** `aria: { label: 'Name' }` in the tag will **not** work.